# Line in text document with most instances of a character

Tags: python, python-3.x

How would you create a function that finds the line of text within a text file with the most instances of a specific character. The function takes two arguments, a text file name and character and outputs the line where the most occurrences of the character occurs

## code so far

```
f = open("filename.txt", "r")

character = input("Enter character: ")
num_chars = 0
lines = f.readlines()
for lines in f:
    for char in line:
        if char == character.lower():
            num_chars += 1
```

This prints out the total number of occurences in the text file and I cannot figure out how to do it properly

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Answer (score 3):

A few hints:

- The `max()` accepts an iterable and a key function.  In your case, the iterable is the file object, and the key function is a function counting characters.
- To count the number of occurrences of a single character in a line, you can use the `count()` method of strings.  To count case-independently, use `lower()` on the whole string first.

Comment: How would you go about stopping at each line? Would you have to use something with \n?

Comment: @EduardoVasquez: Iterating over a file object will in fact iterate over the lines of the file.  Simply passing the file object as first parameter to `max()` will just do the right thing.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example:

```
In [1]: def most(fname, char):
   ...:     with open(fname) as f:
   ...:         return max(f, key = lambda l: l.count(char))
   ...:
```

Note that it doesn't do case conversion and doesn't strip the newline from the end (an exercise for the reader).

```
In [2]: !cat file.txt
foo
bar

In [3]: most('file.txt', 'o')
Out[3]: 'foo\n'

In [4]: most('file.txt', 'b')
Out[5]: 'bar\n'
```

Comment: The lambda function could be replaced by the more efficient `operator.methodcaller("count", char)`.